# How do I connect multiple Peltier modules to one power source?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, peltier, motor-controller

I am making a project which includes

- 8 X Peltier (TEC) modules of specs- 15.4V and 5A
- 3 X Cooling Fans
- 1 X Thermostat to control tempearature
- 1 X Temperature Display unit with Thermocouples
- Some Switches

As I am not so familiar with electrical circuits, I needed help with following points:-

- What power source would I require? Like What power battery should I use? Please provide specs
- How do I connect all these equipments to one battery? If possible, please provide circuit
- How can I control fan speed?

Please consider me a noob in all these. Thanks!

Comment: do the indivudal TECs need independent control, or are they all controlled together?

Comment: They are controlled together.

Comment: An 80Ah leisure battery (not much bigger than a car battery) will power this for an hour to 50% discharge, you don't want to discharge deeper than that if you want the battery to last more than a few cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To power the Peltier modules, you need a power supply capable of delivering 40 Amps (8 x 5 Amp).  This pretty much rules out battery operation as you would need a huge battery bank to provide this power for any significant time.

I would use AC-powered fans (120 or 240 volts depending on your local AC voltage).

You would need a suitable contactor to switch the AC input to the Peltier module power supply - that would be easier than switching the Peltier DC supply directly.

I would use a separate low power/low voltage supply for the thermocouple readout and display and other controls.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the Power supply query but I still need help with the connection of the Power Supply unit with the components. Can you help with that? And also what kind of Power supply do you suggest and can you provide a link of ebay or something like that? Thanks!

Comment: @SahayMaurya This isn't a site for product recommendation.